# `Popover` (as React component) with `OverlayTrigger`

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-component, bootstrap-popover, react-ref

I'm trying to create rich React component as popover content.
If I use example with simple `const popover` (https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/overlays/#examples-1) everything works fine.

#### Problem

But custom react component fails to position itself. It appears on top left of the screen
[image]

```js
const MyPopover = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    return <Popover ref={ref} placement={"bottom"}>
        <Popover.Header as="h3">
            <Form.Control></Form.Control>
        </Popover.Header>
        <Popover.Body>
            <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> Check this info.
        </Popover.Body>
    </Popover>
})

const PopoverChooser = ({children,  container}) => {
    const _refTarget = useRef(null)

    return <>
          <OverlayTrigger
              trigger="click"
              placement="bottom"
              overlay={<MyPopover ref={_refTarget}/>}
              target={_refTarget.current}
          >
              {children} 
          </OverlayTrigger>
    </>
}
export default PopoverChooser;
```

As you can see, I'v tried to use `ref`'s, but it's doesn't help.

#### Question

1. How can it link popover to target button (in image as *dropdown* button and in code as `{children}`).
2. Or should I position `MyPopover` manually (by checking button ID and assigning position.. etc.?)
3. Completely different approach to dig in..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach to forward the ref was right. What you actually forgot is to also inject props. According to the documentation:

> The  and  components do not position themselves.
> Instead the  (or ) components, **inject ref and
> style props**.

https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/overlays/#overview

So what you need to do is to spread the props like this:

```
const MyPopover = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <Popover ref={ref} {...props}>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-sid-0050g9

Comment: Thanks! It worked now :))

I know I was trying these too, but somewhere skipped combination of `{...props}` and `ref={ref}` together :)
Thanks for example in codesandbox